# Scrollable element in Internet Explorer does not remember last position with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

Scrollable content inside `ng-show` element forgets the scroll position in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox.

Run the [Plunker to describe the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/CSwe2LxbxunvLef2HkYB?p=preview) in Internet Explorer and Firefox. You get different results.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Read about **tag omission** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) Use `DIV` and not `P` element when wrapping `OL`, `BUTTON`, `FORM` etc...

Comment: @AlonEitan Fixed that issue in the http://plnkr.co/edit/CSwe2LxbxunvLef2HkYB?p=preview

Comment: This is a great question, but I don't know how to fix it. I also suggest adding reproduction steps (**1.** Click on `Go to bottom` **2.** click on `hidee` **3.** click `Show`, AND describe the expected results vs the actual results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using css `visibility : hidden` instead of `ng-show` clue from @Alon Etian's link [IE10 reset the scrollbars (position to top-left) for a block (overflow:auto) after {display:none, display:block} sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015145/ie10-reset-the-scrollbars-position-to-top-left-for-a-block-overflowauto-aft) in his comment.

[Plunkr that solves this](http://plnkr.co/edit/mU5AP2WjrNaOM60n8ZcY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following workaround - Save the state of the position on the controller and use it to reset the location:

```
  $scope.position = "top"; // Default location of the list
  $scope.show = true;

  $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
    $location.hash('bottom');
    $scope.position = "bottom"; // save the current position 
    $anchorScroll();
  };

  $scope.gotoTop = function() {
    $location.hash('top');
    $scope.position = "top"; // save the current position 
    $anchorScroll();
  };

  $scope.toggleShow = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
    if( $scope.position == "bottom" ) { // If position is "bottom" call "$scope.gotoBottom()" to reset the position
      $timeout(function() { // The code is inside "$timeout" to allow the view to render before updating the location
        $scope.gotoBottom();
      });
    }
  };
```

And on the view, change how you showing/hiding the list:

```
<button ng-click="toggleShow()">{{show ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
```

And don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller:

```
.controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
```

Here is a working example - http://plnkr.co/edit/oXKpmwQtV8ICRvGNeQby?p=preview

Comment: Thank you however the main problem remains - your solution takes care of top/bottom but not the middle or anywhere else. I would like to understand what the underlying problem is in here.

Comment: @bhantol That's why I suggested reproduction steps in my comments :) I didn't thought about this... But check the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015145/ie10-reset-the-scrollbars-position-to-top-left-for-a-block-overflowauto-aft) (Check the jsfillds in the answers) - They have workarounds that you can implement in your app using a directive